# Combine in swift - Not getting updated value for indexPath selected

Tags: ios, swift, combine

```
func bindUI() {
    tableView
        .publisher(for: \UITableView.indexPathForSelectedRow, options: [.new, .old, .initial])
        .compactMap { (indexPath) -> Int in return indexPath?.row ?? 0 }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main, options: nil)
        .sink { [weak self] (row) in self?.label.text = "Selected Row = \(row)" }
        .store(in: &cancellable)
}
```

I am trying to access the selected indexpath by observing the indexPathForSelectedRow key path. Getting initial value but not getting old or new selected values.